# Filter antd table with default search value

Tags: reactjs, antd

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-surf-c1ekpj)

Original Data

[image]

Expect result while first render

(two conditions: name includes 'ji' & age === 32)
[image]

I've tried code like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({ searchText: "ji", searchedColumn: "name" })
  ...
  this.setState({ searchText: "32", searchedColumn: "age" })
}
```

But it's not working because it has to be confirmed after set searchText && searchText.

The function **confirm** seems like it can not be used in componentDidmount.

Does anyone knows how to do it ? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the expected output, do you want to not show John and Joe but only Jim s?

Comment: I want to show data with name includes ji & age is 32, two conditions